# SPA application causing safari low memory crash in IOS 9

Tags: memory, ios9, single-page-application

I'm dealing with a complicated issue that I'm trying to diagnose.

Basically, I have a memory intensive SPA website that is already in production right now and is mobile compatible. Some users are trying to browse the site with IPad Air Devices (1 GB Memory total) and safari is crashing on some areas of the application that require just too much memory.

I connected an ipad air device on XCode Activity monitor and from what I'm seeing the apple webkit process climbs to 280 MB before crashing while loading a specific page.

I did the same test on my laptop with chrome and the same pages settles at 180 MB if the information on the chrome task manager is reliable. However, there's also the GPU process to take into account wich is at 200 MB with this single tab open.

My questions are as follows:

First, what is the most reliable way to see how much memory the website is taking?

Second, If I'm to optimize this website to limit it's memory usage, what's the maximum an ipad air on IOS 9.2 with 1 GB total ram could safely handle?

Feel free to post any valuable tips.

Thanks